# MySQL Query to return next three events from table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query which joins our Account table on a one to many relationship to our Repayment table. I only want to return the first (based on date) three pending Repayments for each account.

So, for example, if i have the following simplified data:

```
loanaccount
encodedkey     id
a1a1a1         a1
b2b2b2         b2
c3c3c3         c3

CREATE TABLE `loanaccount` (
`encodedkey` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`id` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`encodedkey`));
INSERT INTO ``loanaccount` (`encodedkey`, `id`) VALUES ('a1a1a1', 
'a1'),('b2b2b2', 'b2'),('c3c3c3', 'c3');



Repayment
encodedkey   duedate   principaldue   interestdue   parentaccountkey   state
rep1         2018-01-01 7500          5000          a1a1a1           PENDING
rep2         2018-02-01 7500          4000          a1a1a1           PENDING
rep3         2018-03-01 6000          5000          a1a1a1           PENDING
rep4         2017-12-01 4000          4000          a1a1a1           PAID
rep5         2018-01-01 5000          6500          b2b2b2           PENDING
rep6         2018-04-01 6500          5000          b2b2b2           PENDING
rep7         2018-08-01 4000          3000          b2b2b2           PENDING
rep8         2018-09-01 3000          4000          b2b2b2           PENDING
rep9         2018-04-01 8000          4000          a1a1a1           PENDING
rep10        2018-02-01 3500          4000          c3c3c3           PENDING

CREATE TABLE `repayment` (
`encodedkey` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`duedate` DATE NULL,
`principaldue` DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
`interestdue` DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
`parentaccountkey` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
`state` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`encodedkey`));

INSERT INTO repayment (encodedkey, duedate, principaldue, interestdue, parentaccountkey, state) VALUES
('rep1', '2018-01-01', '7500', '5000', 'a1a1a1', 'PENDING'),
('rep2', '2018-02-01', '7500', '4000', 'a1a1a1', 'PENDING'),
('rep3', '2018-03-01', '6000', '5000', 'a1a1a1', 'PENDING'),
('rep4', '2017-12-01', '4000', '4000', 'a1a1a1', 'PAID')   ,
('rep5', '2018-01-01', '5000', '6500', 'b2b2b2', 'PENDING'),
('rep6', '2018-04-01', '6500', '5000', 'b2b2b2', 'PENDING'),
('rep7', '2018-08-01', '4000', '3000', 'b2b2b2', 'PENDING'),
('rep8', '2018-09-01', '3000', '4000', 'b2b2b2', 'PENDING'),
('rep9', '2018-04-01', '8000', '4000', 'a1a1a1', 'PENDING'),
('rep10','2018-02-01', '3500', '4000', 'c3c3c3', 'PENDING');
```

What i would want to show as my results would be:

```
loanaccount.id     rep.duedate   rep.principaldue   rep.interestdue   rep.state
a1                 2018-01-01    7500               5000              PENDING
a1                 2018-02-01    7500               4000              PENDING
a1                 2018-03-01    6000               5000              PENDING
b2                 2018-01-01    5000               6500              PENDING
b2                 2018-04-01    6500               5000              PENDING
b2                 2018-08-01    4000               3000              PENDING
c3                 2018-02-01    3500               4000              PENDING
```

Using help i found elsewhere on this site, i have created a query which will return the earliest pending repayment. It looks like this:

```
select *

from loanaccount la
join (SELECT la.encodedkey
    ,la.id
    , rep.duedate
    ,rep.PRINCIPALDUE
    ,rep.INTERESTDUE
 from loanaccount la
 JOIN (SELECT
  rep.encodedkey
  ,rep.parentaccountkey
  ,min(rep.duedate) as MinDate
  ,rep.principaldue
  ,rep.interestdue
  from repayment rep
  where rep.state = 'PENDING'
  group by rep.parentaccountkey
  ) MinDates on la.ENCODEDKEY = mindates.parentaccountkey 
  join repayment rep on mindates.parentaccountkey = rep.PARENTACCOUNTKEY
  and mindates.mindate = rep.duedate
  where rep.state = 'PENDING'
  ) repa on repa.id = la.id
```

What i'd like to do, is get the 3 earliest duedates from the repayment table for each account. The repayments don't necessarily fit a standard schedule - i.e. not all monthly or quarterly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: An answer which was removed mentioned ranking functionality - this isn't something i was aware of. I'm looking into this as a viable option.

Comment: 1. Store dates as dates. 2. Don't store '£'. 3. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry - thank you, I'm a very infrequent user of the site so good to have a reference to ensure my questions are relevant and clear. I have made some small edits to the original question.

Comment: Good. But let us know when you make the big edits requested above.

Comment: Added detail, CREATE and INSERT statements for sample data, and expected results based on the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT duedate
     , principaldue
     , interestdue
     , state 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.* 
            , CASE WHEN @prev = parentaccountkey THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
            , @prev:=parentaccountkey prev 
         FROM repayment x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        WHERE state = 'pending' 
        ORDER 
           BY parentaccountkey
            , duedate
     ) a
 WHERE rank <= 3;
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
| duedate    | principaldue | interestdue | state   |
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
| 2018-01-01 |      7500.00 |     5000.00 | PENDING |
| 2018-02-01 |      7500.00 |     4000.00 | PENDING |
| 2018-03-01 |      6000.00 |     5000.00 | PENDING |
| 2018-01-01 |      5000.00 |     6500.00 | PENDING |
| 2018-04-01 |      6500.00 |     5000.00 | PENDING |
| 2018-08-01 |      4000.00 |     3000.00 | PENDING |
| 2018-02-01 |      3500.00 |     4000.00 | PENDING |
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
```

The bit about joining the other table has been left as an exercise for the reader